# How to fetch a dictionary from an array based on a particular key in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nspredicate

Hi in my application I have an array which contains a group of dictionaries. Each dictionary has three key value pairs. Out of three two are start date and end date. Now I want to pass a date and have it fetch a dictionary from an array where the date will be in between start and end date. If the date is not within the range of start and end dates then have to check in another dictionary and have to fetch that dictionary. Can any one please help me to do this.

**Date (DD/MM/YYYY):** 13/04/2014

*Start Date:* 03/04/2014

*End Date:* 31/04/2014

**Dictionaries:**

```
NSDictionary *dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"Scode",@"01-04-2014",@"StartDate",@"15-04-2014",@"EndDate",nil];
NSDictionary *dic1=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"Scode",@"16-04-2014",@"StartDate",@"25-04-2014",@"EndDate",nil];    
NSDictionary *dic3=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",@"Scode",@"26-04-2014",@"StartDate",@"30-04-2014",@"EndDate"nil];
```

**Result:**

```
 NSPredicate *predicateName;
 predicateName=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"StartDate <=%@ && EndDate >=%@",date,date];
 NSArray *arrResult=[tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateName];
 NSMutableArray *arrSearchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrResult];
```

If date  is 1-4-2014 arrSearchResults is:

```
({
    EndDate = "15-04-2014";
    StartDate = "01-04-2014";
    SCode = 0;
})
```

If date is 2-04-2014 arrSearchResults is:

```
({
    EndDate = "25-04-2014";
    StartDate = "16-04-2014";
    SCode = 1;
})
```

Comment: Did you tried anything to solve your problem? If yes then Share your tried process and code else you try first. :)

Comment: Please post the dictionary here first.

Comment: Hi tihomFreak I edited my question can you please check it once.

Comment: @user3341324 did you got your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the answer:

```
    NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSDictionary *dic=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0",@"Scode",@"01-04-2014",@"StartDate",@"15-04-2014",@"EndDate",nil];

    NSDictionary *dic1=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"Scode",@"16-04-2014",@"StartDate",@"25-04-2014",@"EndDate",nil];

    NSDictionary *dic2=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"2",@"Scode",@"26-04-2014",@"StartDate",@"30-04-2014",@"EndDate",nil];

    [arr addObject:dic];
    [arr addObject:dic1];
    [arr addObject:dic2];

     NSPredicate *predicateName;
     predicateName=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"StartDate <=%@ && EndDate >=%@",@"02-04-2014",@"02-04-2014"];
     NSArray *arrResult=[arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateName];
     NSMutableArray *arrSearchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrResult];
```

arrSearchResults will be the result.

Replace 02-04-2014 date as the your date using which you want to apply the filter.

Comment: Predicates will filter considering the startDate and endDate as strings.

Comment: @ Himanshu A Jadav : so what if you properly formatted the string it will give you the correct result. I tried this and then posted on SO. Have you checked it before doing the -1. Please check it before doing -1

Comment: @ Himanshu A Jadav: if you want you can execute the above code snippet and then check for the other dates also:)

Comment: Hi svrushal thanks a lot for your reply.Your answer helps me upto some extend I need more help from your side.Actually my requirement is I have one date that will come in a loop like first 1 will come second 2 will come and so on. When ever i get a date i have to check wehter that date is in first dic range or in second dic date range or third dic date range. Based on that i have to fetch Scode from that dic. Can you please help me.

Comment: @user3341324 then it is easy na...I think for the loop you have used the for loop...Then in for loop fire that NSPredicate. To get the Scode, arrSearchResults will be the result which contains the dictionary. Then retrieve the dictionary from arrSearchResults and then Scode key value.

Comment: If you like the answer then can you please accept it and upvote the same

Comment: Hi I am getting wrong data. For your reference I am editing my question with answer what i am getting.

Comment: Hi Svrushal can you please check my question.

Comment: i think problem is, 1-4-2014. You have to format it as 01-04-2014. Month and day should be 2 digit.

Comment: Hi Svrushal please check the question.

Comment: Hi Svrushal ur correct. I am getting the proper data but when  ever the date equals to end date that time I am getting the array as NULL.

Comment: But we have written the formatter as Enddate>=your date...you should get right data.Can u please debug it properly.

Comment: Hi I checked I am using in this way.             predicateName=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"StartDate<=%@ && EndDate>=%@",date,date];

Comment: what is the value of date then?? Have you tried to print the  predicateName in console

Comment: Hi I checked. This is how it is coming  predicateName is StartDate <= "15-4-2014" AND EndDate >= "15-4-2014"
2014-04-18 12:33:01.693 iDemo[2775:60b] arrSearchResults is (
)

Comment: thats what i m saying 15-4-2014 should be 15-04-2014. Do one thing hard code value as 15-04-2014. see the result if you get right answer then problem is your date format. I would suggest write function which will convert the day and month value as two digit. if you did that then your headache will minimize.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do here:

1) Extract startDate and endDate from the array.

2) Format the two dates with a date formatter

3) Now, compare the two dates with the current date as follows,

According to Apple documentation of NSDate compare:

```
 if (([currentDate compare:startDate] == NSOrderedDescending) && ([currentDate compare:endDate] == NSOrderedAscending))
{
//Date lies in between two dates
}
```

Hope it helps.